# Add columns to a new level in multiindex dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

My dataframe looks like this:

```py
data = {
 'WholesalerID': {0: 121, 1: 121, 2: 42, 3: 42, 4: 54, 5: 43, 6: 432, 7: 4245, 8: 4245, 9: 4245, 10: 457},
 'Brand': {0: 'Vans', 1: 'Nike', 2: 'Nike', 3: 'Vans',4: 'Vans', 5: 'Nike', 6: 'Puma', 7: 'Vans', 8: 'Nike', 9: 'Puma', 10: 'Converse'},
 'Shop 1': {0: 'Yes', 1: 'No', 2: 'Yes', 3: 'Maybe', 4: 'Yes', 5: 'No', 6: 'Yes', 7: 'Yes', 8: 'Maybe', 9: 'Maybe', 10: 'No'}
}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)

df = df.assign(count=1)
pivoted_df = pd.pivot_table(
    df,
    index=["Brand"],
    columns=["Shop 1"],
    values=["count"],
    aggfunc={"count": "count"},
    fill_value=0,
    margins=True,
    margins_name="N",
)
```

[image]

I need to add columns `N, Count, Prop` on the first level, I am trying the following, but It does not work:

```
pivoted_df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(
    [pivoted_df.columns, ["N", "count", "prop"]]
)
```

**Desired output**:[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to do it with Pandas [indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/advanced.html) and [concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```py
dfs = []
for col in ("Yes", "Maybe", "No"):
    tmp = (
        pivoted_df.loc[:"Vans", [("count", col), ("count", "N")]]
        .rename(columns={col: "count"})
        .rename(columns={"count": col}, level=0)
    )
    tmp[(col, "prop")] = tmp[(col, "count")] / tmp[(col, "N")]
    dfs.append(tmp.reindex(columns=[(col, "N"), (col, "count"), (col, "prop")]))

new_df = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1)
```

Then:

```py
print(new_df)
# Output
         Yes             Maybe             No
Shop 1     N count  prop     N count  prop  N count prop
Brand
Converse   1     0  0.00     1     0  0.00  1     1  1.0
Nike       4     1  0.25     4     1  0.25  4     2  0.5
Puma       2     1  0.50     2     1  0.50  2     0  0.0
Vans       4     3  0.75     4     1  0.25  4     0  0.0
```